# Waiting for database connection before starting up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I actually have been stuck at waiting for the database to be ready before launching services. Am using `docker-compose.yml` with `NodeJS`. Am  using [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on) and all my connections happen through links `nats://nats:4222`, `redis://redis:6379/2` and `mysql:3306`. How do use the `wait-on` package to wait for these services before bootstrapping the service. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `depends_on` in your `docker-compose.yml`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

It will wait your dbs to be started before starting your app

Comment: That documentation link explicitly says: "`depends_on` does not wait for [its dependencies] to be "ready" before starting [the container] - only until they have been started."  You generally need some kind of "wait" tool, or for your application to tolerate the database being temporarily unavailable.